# Defining custom-checkbox in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

### How to make a custom check-Box in android

**my current XML**::

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_individualdays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_type_of_days"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mon" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tue" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wed" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thu" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**Out-Put**::

[image]

**But How to make something like below**::

[image]

- here blue border shows its selected
- else its not selected
- It has to be a check-box

***Hope i am clear !***

Comment: This Link May help You

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353608/create-custom-check-boxes-in-android

Comment: Try this demo http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/1257/

Comment: Here is a circle checkbox https://github.com/arlindiDev/CircleCheckBox

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use this code

select.xml in drawable folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" >
        </solid>

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ff0000" >
        </stroke>
<corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

deselect.xml in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" >
        </solid>

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000000" >
        </stroke>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

and custom checkbox

```
public class checkbox extends CheckBox{



    public checkbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            //setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
        }
        @Override
        public void setChecked(boolean t){
            if(t)
            {
                this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.select);
            }
            else
            {
                this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deselect);
            }
            super.setChecked(t);
        }
        }
```

checkbox

```
 <com.example.checkbox.checkbox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="checked" />
```

you can change color in select.xml and deselect.xml to thing that you want

Answer (score 16):

For your requirement I prefer you to use CheckedTextView instead of CheckBox.Here is the code what you wanted.

```
 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/ctv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mon" 
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:checked="true"
    android:background="@drawable/chk_indicator"
    android:padding="15dp"
   />
```

create 3 xml ( chk_indicator.xml , chk_bg.xml , chk_pressed_bg.xml )in drawable folder

chk_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked ="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/chk_pressed_bg" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/chk_bg" />

</selector>
```

chk_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

         <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

         <stroke android:width="3dp"
             android:color="#ababab"/>

        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

chk_pressed_bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

         <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

         <stroke android:width="3dp"
             android:color="#5e9eff"/>

        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

output:

[image]

set onClick event on CheckedTextView

```
 ((CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.ctv)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            boolean isChecked = ((CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.ctv)).isChecked();

            if(isChecked)
              ((CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.ctv)).setChecked(false);
            else
              ((CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.ctv)).setChecked(true);




        }
    });
```

Comment: Very good i/p [+1] from me too .... but this solution is perfect in the usecase where the button must always be selected .... we cannnot deselect this ! .... but this also helps :)

Comment: @smriti3 we can select or deselect it based on input because it is CheckedTextView.U can use isChecked() method.

Comment: @smriti3 check my updated code.U can set click event and handle whether the CheckedTextView isChecked or not.

Comment: This works ....correct ...thanks ! ... i already checked other answer as correct ... but I have upvoted your answer .... thanks for sharing this solution :)

Comment: @smriti3 okey.glad it helped.

Comment: @TheFlash thanks...but what if we want to change size of text when it is checked??

Comment: @Shaishav Jogani u need to programmatically change the size of text

Answer (score 2):

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Wed"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

[image]

Try like this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [zohreh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20015719/1972597), you could get the checkbox with text only and get rid of the checkbox icon as shown below,

[image]

For this, set the button drawable to null in the constructor of the custom checkbox class, as shown below,

```
public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // Don't show the checkbox.
    setButtonDrawable(null);
}
```