# Stroke not getting applied along with selector in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a **layout.xml** like the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowImageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow_selector"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow">
    </ImageButton>        
</LinearLayout>
```

I have **left_arrow_selector.xml** like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>   
    </item>

</selector>
```

Everything else is working fine but the stroke is not getting applied.
Please advice on this.

EDIT - Added Image...
The Image is there which i want to keep it same but i want to add stroke to the view. Please see how i added a grey stroke if i removed the selector.

[image]

Comment: I can't make sense of your selector. There are 3 consecutive states and **no one points to a resource**. Then there is an **extra (alien) shape** with only a stroke (no shape's shape - if you pass me the joke)... You could **just add the black stroke to your picture**...

Comment: Agree with Bob..can u post image?@Coder_sLaY

Comment: @BobMalooga I am changing the background color on press of the view. I also want to have a stroke along with it.

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: Could you post a picture of the desired results? I think a couple of PNGs pointed by the selector items will simply do the trick. One with a white fill and another one with a green fill. The latter having a black border too.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015463/defining-custom-checkbox-in-android/20015800#20015800..it may help to u..@Coder_sLaY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_left_white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_left_white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_left_green" />
</selector>
```

and add:

`/res/drawable/arrow_left_white.xml` (just to preserve the name in the selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/grey" />
    <solid android:color="@color/azure">
</shape>
```

and

`/res/drawable/arrow_left_green.xml` (also just to preserve the name in the selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
    <solid android:color="@color/brown">
</shape>
```

So, setting the selector as your background and the image as your src, you'll have a stateful ImageButton that turns (with the colors I choosed) from beaing a yellow left triangle on an azure background and having a grey border to the same yellow triangle on a brown backgrounf with a black border.

stroke for the border
solid for the fill

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

You can add some spice by rounding the corners and/or using gradients.

Comment: I can't do it like this. See i have attached the image.

Comment: Nothing easier. grey border + yellow triangle -> black border + green triangle?

Comment: Black Border + Green Background. The yellow triangle is constant. Changed code to grey stroke now.

Comment: So! now I got it. bg + border change, the image is fixed. Let me think to it a bit...

Comment: I edited my answer. Pretty self explanatory, I think. Of, course, choose some better colors than mine... :)

Comment: Nice to be helpful, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

try this instead:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

That happens when you copy&paste too much ^^

Comment: This one makes more sense.