# Android Like Button Implementation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a like button with two states in my app but i am confused on what type of button that is used in android app's like instagram and facebook is it a normal button,image button or a toggle button, i've searched around for this but i haven't gotten any answers, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sleek implementation would be to create a Custom ImageView, which has an object (boolean, int, etc) that maintains it's state. You maintain this state by it's onClickListener associated with the imageview, and set the drawable to be a new image corresponding to it's respective state when triggered.

For example, say you have a "like" button similar to Facebook's. Initially, it has a background drawable of a gray thumb and say our state is a boolean value which is false when gray. When a user clicks on the thumb, state would change to true and the image drawable becomes blue indicating it has been activated. We know to make the drawable the blue version because that state is now "true".

So each click event would swap states, and set the drawable to be a new image based on state. This implies have multiple types of images.

EDIT:

Additionally, this could actually be a button with Text in it and a drawable using [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) , [drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) , etc... which you change the text color and corresponding drawable on state change via method in your Custom Button implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom checkbox. When the user presses the checkbox, it changes to the like state. If it's already checked, uncheck the box.

Here is the question I found: [Defining custom-checkbox in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015463/defining-custom-checkbox-in-android)