# Is there anyway make checkbox work like this?

Tags: android, checkbox

[image]

What I want is when I click at "2" zone, it will show a fragment instead of checking the box. The box will be checked when I click at "1" zone.

At last try, I created a relativelayout contain with a checkbox and a textview, but the result is very horrible when I change background of the layout (it color the checkbox also), that is why I return to checkbox. So anyone have any idea? please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015463/defining-custom-checkbox-in-android

Comment: This sounds like bad UI as many users expect that if they click the text associated to a checkbox, it also checks the box.

Comment: You can use selector for this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192173/change-icons-of-checked-and-unchecked-for-checkbox-for-android